# What is up with Linux and Apache's ".d"?

Tags: linux, apache, configuration

Linux and Apache suffix a bunch of files and folders with `d` or `.d`.

```
init.d
rc.d
/etc/httpd/conf.d
/etc/httpd/vhost.d
```

What is the meaning of this convention?

Comment: Voting to move to SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Why was this closed and not moved?

Comment: no idea, I flagged for moving. It's a majority decision :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means simply "directory" and commonly indicates that either a single file, or a directory full of them is acceptable for configuration.

(In the case of `rc.d`, that replaces the old-style Unix `/etc/rc` script which is no longer used on Linux.)

Comment: Just curios, `/etc/rc.local` is, though. Isn't it?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: yes, `rc.local` is a remnant of the old, BSD-style system initialization. I've never edited an `rc.local` file on a Linux box, though.

Answer (score 1):

Means "a directory", containing a bunch of files intended for the same goal (init scripts in `init.d`, configuration files in `conf.d`, etc.) - this tendency seems to have expanded onto separate files, too.